# How JavaScript get a variable from C#?

Tags: web-part, server

In my project, I want to pass a variable from C# to Javascript, but i am fail :(

code:

C#

```
public partial class partpart: WebPart
    {
       string str= string.Empty;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            str = "dog";
        }

    }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var jsStr= '<%=str%>';
        console.log(jsStr);
 });
```

What is the best way to pass variable (include string array) from C# in SharePoint web part?

Comment: You can use hidden field. Store value using C# code and access that value in javascript function using it's id.

Comment: @DikeshGandhi so, using hidden field is the best way to pass variable in web part?

Comment: Yes. You can use this. Otherwise you can get and set custom webpart properties also.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are developing a web part, follow the article [Creating a Web Part with Client-side Script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584169(v=office.11).aspx) that describes how to embed JavaScript code from server side code.

In case of array you could utilize [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration Method (String, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerarraydeclaration(v=vs.110).aspx) that:

> Registers a JavaScript array declaration with the Page object using an
>   array name and array value.

Here is an example:

```
public class MyWebPart : WebPart
{

      public MyWebPart()
      {
            this.PreRender += new EventHandler(MyWebPart_PreRender);
      }


      private void MyWebPart_PreRender(object sender , System.EventArgs e )
      {
           String arrName = "cities";
           String arrValue = "\"London\", \"Berlin\", \"Paris\"";
           ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
           // Register the array with the Page class.
           cs.RegisterArrayDeclaration(arrName, arrValue);
           //...
      }

}
```